# How to make required fields in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make all my fields required for when I press Next button that submit and go to the next form. I need all these to be required I don't know how to do it for all types of text box, check box, select, and radio button.

```
<div class="container tb-10">
   <form>
      <div>
        <div class="row">
            <h4>Food Stamps (SNAP) / EBT Cards:</h4>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Please name the person (whether you or a member of your household) who receives food stamps, and city and state where they are received.</label>
                <div>
                    Relationship to you: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_relationship" id="snap_relationship" required placeholder="Relationship to you" >
                </div>

                <div>
                    City: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snap_city" id="snap_city" required placeholder="City" >
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="state" class="form-label">State:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="State" id="state">
                        <option selected>Select State...</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <button id="exit" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" >Exit</button>
        <button id="submitform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" routerLink ="/referrals" > Next </button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-benefits',
  templateUrl: './benefits.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./benefits.component.css']
})
export class BenefitsComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a full example using form group with a textbox and select

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      textbox: ['', Validators.required],
      select: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log('Form submitted:', this.form.value);
    } else {
      console.log('Form is not valid');
    }
  }
}


<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <!-- Textbox -->
  <div>
    <label for="textbox">Textbox:</label>
    <input id="textbox" type="text" formControlName="textbox">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.textbox.invalid && (form.controls.textbox.dirty || form.controls.textbox.touched)">
      <small class="error-text">Textbox is required</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Select dropdown -->
  <div>
    <label for="select">Select:</label>
    <select id="select" formControlName="select">
      <option value="" disabled>Select an option</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.select.invalid && (form.controls.select.dirty || form.controls.select.touched)">
      <small class="error-text">You must select an option</small>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I get a error on html file underline the textbox button.

Comment: share the error

Comment: Property 'textbox' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['textbox'].  @Hezy Ziv

Comment: it should run as is, its a suggestion you can change to <div *ngIf="form.controls['textbox'].invalid && (form.controls['textbox'].dirty || form.controls['textbox'].touched)">
  <small class="error-text">Textbox is required</small>
</div>

Comment: Ok I see that I'm trying to incorporate this with my logic but yours alot different I'm getting errors

Comment: Can you use the example with my code since it's different than what you posted. @Hezy Ziv

Comment: follow my first answer and add this below the textbox  <div *ngIf="showErrors && !myForm.controls['exampleInput'].valid">
    This field is required.
  </div>

Comment: Div the one above that's checked or the one below?

Comment: below the <input> textbox

Comment: I was referring to which answer

Answer (score 0):

ok lets go one by one to your text you have added required
your select first option  should have value  = ""

```
<option selected value="">Select State...</option>
```

now add a form model to your app.module.ts

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    FormsModule
  ],
  // ...
})
```

change the form tag

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
```

now validate the form on submit

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class BenefitsComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.router.navigate(['/referrals']);
    } else {
      // Handle the invalid form (e.g., show a message to the user)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I done this what about for my text boxes @Hezy Ziv

Comment: your textbox is required, the form will be invalid as log as textbox is empty. you can a dd validation fields, to show the error to the user

Comment: So how I do that show the message?

Comment: Thanks bro when I try this i'll check your box!

Comment: I'm getting mini errors to fix this,it's not working for me